# Can't write to a file with sshfs

Tags: sshfs

I'm trying to mount a directory from a remote machine to my laptop.
Here is the command.

```
 sshfs user01:/home/user01/somedir /home/user02/mount -o allow_other -o rw
```

When I try to write a file, I get:

```
E212: Can't open file for writing
```

Here are the contents of /etc/fuse.conf

```
user_allow_other
```

The permission of the remote dir of /home/user01/somedir

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user01 users
```

I prefer not to change the permissions on the remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the command that worked.

```
 sshfs -o sftp_server="/usr/bin/sudo -u user01 /usr/libexec/sftp-server" you@<server>:/home/user01 /source/home_dir/mountpoint
```

Make sure on destination server `usr/libexec/sftp-server` is the correct path, or adjust.